# Remove warning "i18next: init: i18next is already initialized. You should call init just once"

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, i18next, react-i18next, vitest

I have an application where I want to use 2 configurations of i18next, one for the app and another for my tests, the problem is that when I run my tests, if the instance is used for testing and my tests pass but I have the warning in the terminal:

init: i18next is already initialized. You should call init just once!

[this is what it looks like at the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktvWR.png)

**i18n for app:**

```js
// i18n.ts
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        load: 'languageOnly',
        fallbackLng: localStorage.getItem('lang') ?? 'es',
        debug: import.meta.env.DEV,
    });

export default i18n;
```

**usage in main app:**

```js
// main.tsx

...

import './i18n';

...
```

**and the config for my test:**

```js
// i18nForTests.ts

import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    lng: 'es',
    fallbackLng: 'es',
    ns: ['translationsNS'],
    defaultNS: 'translationsNS',
    debug: false,
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
    },
    resources: { es: { translationsNS: {} } },
});

export default i18n;
```

**usage:**

```js
// setupTests.ts

...
import './i18nForTests';
...
```

Is there another way to do it? I don't want the "Backend" and "LanguageDetector" middleware to be used in my tests.

I have already tried the methods described in the [documentation here](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing)

Even with  passing my instance for testing, but this way for some reason, it uses the main instance instead of the test instance.

```js
import i18nForTest from "./i18nForTests"

const WithProviders = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
    <MemoryRouter>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18nForTest}>
            <ChakraProvider>{children}</ChakraProvider>
        </I18nextProvider>
    </MemoryRouter>
);
```

[warning with I18nextProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1m3S.png)

I'm using vitest with react-testing-library, here is the config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './src/setupTests.ts',
    coverage: {
      provider: 'v8'
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the actual error: show the error, don't paraphrase it. It's telling you which file/line things are going wrong on, which is pretty important if you want to address it. Also, if you don't want certain code to run as part of your test, have you already tried running it conditionally by checking whether whatever flags or values are globally accessible during testing are there or not?

Comment: I have updated the question with an image of what the terminal looks like with the message, I hope that helps to better understand the question, it is important to emphasize that it is not an error, it is a warning.
I understand your validation point, however, in my opinion I don't think it applies since the file where the main instance is called is the entry point file of my app(main.ts), file that I think should not matter since in my tests I am testing the components in isolation and that file should not be taken into account by my tests, correct? for the tests config I have the setupTests

Comment: In this case, it's not: copy-paste the text (you'll lose the coloring, but the color is purely cosmetic). The rules are pretty explicit in that you should never post pictures of text. to the point where it's in bold _and_ all-caps. This looks like jest (so it's a good idea to add that tag), in which case you should probably turn on verbose mode to get all the details. But also, did you try to add a simple conditional that checks whether Jest is running or not? Because https://jestjs.io/docs/environment-variables exists essentially exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solved

The problem is that in the test environment I was taking into account both instances because both were initialized automatically in each file through the chaining of the init method:

```js
i18n.use(Backend)
        .use(LanguageDetector)
        .use(initReactI18next)
        .init({ // this part
            load: 'languageOnly',
            fallbackLng: localStorage.getItem('lang') ?? 'es',
            debug: import.meta.env.DEV,
        });
```

The solution was as obvious as @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans pointed out, control the initialization, in my case I did it by putting the code inside a function and executing it where it was needed, the same for the test configuration:

```js
function initI18nProd() {
    i18n.use(Backend)
        .use(LanguageDetector)
        .use(initReactI18next)
        .init({
            load: 'languageOnly',
            fallbackLng: localStorage.getItem('lang') ?? 'es',
            debug: import.meta.env.DEV,
        });
}

export default initI18nProd;
```

and in the implementation:

```
// main.ts
...
import initI18nProd from './i18n';

initI18nProd();
...
```

```
// setupTests.ts
import initI18nTests from './i18nForTests';

initI18nTests()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use the "createInstance" method of i18next - here is the documentation - https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#createinstance

```js
// i18n.ts
import i18n as i18next from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const i18n = i18next.createInstance();
i18n.use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        load: 'languageOnly',
        fallbackLng: localStorage.getItem('lang') ?? 'es',
        debug: import.meta.env.DEV,
    });

export default i18n;
```

And the same goes for tests

```js
// i18nForTests.ts

import i18n as i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const i18n = i18next.createInstance();
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    lng: 'es',
    fallbackLng: 'es',
    ns: ['translationsNS'],
    defaultNS: 'translationsNS',
    debug: false,
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
    },
    resources: { es: { translationsNS: {} } },
});

export default i18n;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this solution but it didn't work, this way when running the tests it takes the main instance and ignores the test instance despite having imported the instance in the setupTests file, it uses the one in the main.ts file.